# Rebuilding .zip file from base64 encoded .zip file clob

Tags: java, base64, zip, clob

We've recently implemented functionality to load "*.zip" files from sFTP. However before we've implemented the functionality there was already couple of "*.zip" files in there which were treated as ordinary "*.xml" files and downloaded. Now I have a task to restore those downloaded files to zip format.

ZIP files were treated as xml and in doing so they were downloaded in following manner,

> CLOB file = downloadFile(channelSFTP.get(fileName), oConn);

:

```
    private static CLOB downloadFile(InputStream is, OracleConnection oConn) throws Exception {
        CLOB clob = CLOB.createTemporary(oConn, true, CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);

        Writer writer = clob.setCharacterStream(1);
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int length = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            result.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        result.flush();

        writer.write(result.toString("UTF-8"));
        writer.flush();

        return clob;
    }
```

Then the CLOB is returned from java stored procedure to oracle procedure, and ENCODED in BASE64.

What I've tried to restore files:

```
public static void decodeZip(String path, String resPath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(new FileInputStream(path), bos);
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream((InputStream) new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));

        ZipEntry entry;
        while((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println(entry.getName());
        }
    }
```

Where "path" is the path of the BASE64 encoded file. However I'm getting the following error:

> java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths

on "zis.getNextEntry()". I think it should be possible to achieve this, but i can't seem to figure out, what step I'am missing.

Comment: You've got multiple stages of transformation here. You need to work out what's going wrong. Ideally, get the original zip file and the base64 file on the same machine. Then you can use other base64 decoders to see whether decoding that gets you the original zip file. You can also write the results of base64 decoding in Java into a file, and diff that to the original zip file too.

Comment: Thanks for advice, however after further investigation I don't think it's possible. In database layer, clob is being stripped of CRLF, base64 encoded, and converted to blob, via oracle's dbms_lob.convertClobToBlob, which is a blackbox. When trying to convert via the same steps., length of the result clob is just a couple of characters, everything else is lost. When decoding with Java, files are a lot more similar, however, still differ.

Comment: You don't think *what's* possible? Recovering the data? Certainly if you don't get back the string that you put into the database, you'll have problems. I don't understand how you're getting more data when fetching with Java though. (It's odd to talk about base64-encoding a CLOB though - base64 encoding turns binary into text; the CLOB is already text.)

Comment: I think oracle's dbms_lob converter, strips a lot of symbols which it can't convert and Java doesn't, as I said dbms_lob package is a blackbox so I can't be certain. Before encoding clob is being converted to blob, and then encoded to base64.

Comment: Well you can *at least* check that you can store (in Oracle) and then retrieve a string correctly from Java, by the sounds of it. So do that. You can still definitely separate out the various steps here.

Comment: Note that if you were treating arbitrary binary data as if it were UTF-8-encoded text, then you've almost certainly already lost data. It's unclear whether that's what you're doing in `downloadFile` or whether the input stream really contains UTF-8 data. Again, that's something *you* can check but we can't.

Comment: With plain text files i had no problems so far. But i think that because zip file wasn't plain text a lot of bytes were interpreted badly by dbms_lob converter.

Comment: Yes, the data was treated as UTF-8-encoded text.

Comment: Okay, then you should probably just accept that you've lost that information. Think of the situation the same way you would if it turned out you'd only saved every other byte of a file.